# Macro to filter on an active cell from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, filter, worksheet

I am trying to filter on a column, using value from another worksheet. I want to be able to click anywhere in Column B from Spreadsheet S1 and be able to filter on Column A in Spreadsheet S2 using value of Column A in the same row in S1. Using the code below, I am able to filter on Column A in S2 using value in Cell A3.

```
Sheets("S2").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "=" & Sheets("S1").Range("A3"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

End Sub

I want to be able to use the code below to be able to pick the value from column A that is on the left of `ActiveCell`, instead of saying A3 (as in the code above).

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell. Select
        Selection.Copy
```

What should I use as `Criteria1:=` to be able to achieve this. Using `"=" & ActiveCell .Value, Operator:=x1And` lets me use the value in S2 but `"=" & Sheets("S1").Range(ActiveCell. Value), Operator:=x1And` gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673(v=office.15).aspx) is unique throughout the entire `Application` (Excel)

so if you want to jump between sheets and still reference a *specific* `Worksheet` `"ActiveCell"` (i.e. the cell that would be the actual `Application.ActiveCell` if that *specific* `Worksheet` were the active one) then you must first store it in a variable of `Range` type before leaving that *specific* `Worksheet`:

```
Dim MyActiveCell As Range

Set MyActiveCell = ActiveCell ' store the reference to currently active cell of active sheet 

Sheets("S2").Activate ' "jump" to another Worksheet

Sheets("S2").Range("$A$1:$N$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value ' use MyActiveCell to reference the "active" cell previously stored
```

but you can also avoid "sheet-jumping": if your current active `Worksheet` is the one you want to reference its `ActiveCell` and use it for "S2" `Worksheet` filtering, you can go:

```
Sheets("S2").Range("$A$1:$N$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value ', Operator:=xlAnd
```

and go on "staying" in the active sheet while "acting" on other sheets by just fully qualifying ranges and calling methods on them

```
Sheets("MyOtherSheet").Range("MyOtherSheetRangeAddress").ProperRangeMethod
```

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. Thank you